# I am trying to scan the file provided, and add 1 to a list for each "A"

Tags: python

Like the title. Please help. Eventually, I want to have a function thats able to scan multiple letters. But the code I have just gives me an empty list

```
import sys
script, filename = sys.argv
txt= open(filename)


def dna_():
    list_=[]
    a=0
    txt.read(1)
    for line in txt:
        while "A" in line:
            list_.append(a)
            a += 1
            return list_
    print (list_)
dna_()
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @DannyXu, can you provide an example of what you have in your file, adnd what is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: `return [1] * txt.read().count('A')`?

Comment: The file contains random letters, for example: ASHDJDINAAAYEH.        And I hope to make the output a list counting A : [4] thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So there is a better way to do this than reading the lines one at a time.  If you want to count the occurences of the letter 'A' or 'a', you can use the string built in function count().   Here is an example using the first paragraph from python's License.txt file:

```
A. HISTORY OF THE SOFTWARE
==========================

Python was created in the early 1990s by Guido van Rossum at Stichting
Mathematisch Centrum (CWI, see http://www.cwi.nl) in the Netherlands
as a successor of a language called ABC.  Guido remains Python's
principal author, although it includes many contributions from others.
```

You can read the entire file into a list using the 'readlines()' functon:

```
text = open('LICENSE.txt')
lineList = text.readlines()
```

lineList will look like this:

```
['A. HISTORY OF THE SOFTWARE\n', '==========================\n', '\n', 'Python was created in the early 1990s by Guido van Rossum at Stichting\n', 'Mathematisch Centrum (CWI, see http://www.cwi.nl) in the Netherlands\n', "as a successor of a language called ABC.  Guido remains Python's\n", 'principal author, although it includes many contributions from others.\n']
```

now you can just change this to a string by combining all the lines:

```
myString = ''.join(lineList)
```

This creates a string 'myString':

```
"A. HISTORY OF THE SOFTWARE\n==========================\n\nPython was created in the early 1990s by Guido van Rossum at Stichting\nMathematisch Centrum (CWI, see http://www.cwi.nl) in the Netherlands\nas a successor of a language called ABC.  Guido remains Python's\nprincipal author, although it includes many contributions from others.\n"
```

Now to get all the letter 'a'/'A's, you can just count the lower case instance of this string:

```
aCount = myString.lower().count('a')  #this will include all the upper and lower case a's.
```

One final note, your use of the:
    txt.read(1)

This will only pull the first character from your line.  So if your first letter in your file isn't an 'a', then its going to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on comments, I have improved my answer

There are quite a few issues, and the easiest way to explain is to show the code:

```py
import sys
script, filename = sys.argv

txt = open(filename)
lines = txt.readlines() # this reads all lines from file at once, and makes it easier later
txt.close()             # it's good practice to close your files

def dna_():
    a = 0
    for line in lines:      # iterate through lines
        for char in line:   # iterate through each character
            if char == "A": # check for "A"
                a += 1
    return [a]              # move return statement out of loop
    # print (list_)         # this print statement is skipped by the return

print(dna_())
```

Reading the input data all at once makes it a lot easier to deal with later on.

Your code gave me [0] on a test file, since the list is returned in a loop. Return statements should only be used when the value you're returning is finished and ready to be outputted.

Your `while` statement is always true, since it doesn't iterate through the line. If there's a line with an "A", the while condition will always be true, and the loop will never stop.

Your final print statement will be skipped, since a function stops running once a `return` statement is hit.

Calling this function outputs a list, so to actually do something with the list, you'd have to assign it to a variable. I just printed it so I could the result.

Finally, in this code, `a` acts as a counter. At the end, this number gets wrapped in `[]` to form a list of one element, `a`.

This code gives the desired output for your example text file. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the buildin [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) ?

```
with open("some_file") as f:
    for x in f.readlines():
        print(x.count('A')) # number of occurrences of A in line
```